# Flask app needs static files to be in two locations to show up

Tags: python, flask

I'm using `send_from_directory` in flask to serve some static js assets.  The app structure looks like this:

```
/BaseFolder
    /App
        __init__.py
        /js/
            jquery.js
    run.py
    /js/
        jquery.js
```

The `__init__.py` is responsible for most of the app management and has the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
[...]
@app.route('/js/<path:path>')
def send_js(path):
    return send_from_directory('js',path)
[...]
def go():
    [...]
    app.run()
```

The app itself kicks off from the run.py file which runs the go function in the file above.  (this essentially mirrors the app setup of the app in *Flask Web Development* so it should be a typical use case for Flask.)

Theoretically, the send_js function should return a file from either the App/js/ or the js/ directory.  However, removing either of these files causes the application to 404.  (The app serves the contents of the lower one; even `touch js/jquery.js` in the upper folder is enough to make things work.)

Why does this happen?

Comment: To understand why is that happening just add the import os; print os.getcwd() right before the send_from_directory call. That will give you a current working directory for your python process.

Comment: Ah, something weird is happening there, but changing the directory in go() seemed to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the application runs from run.py, it thinks that its current directory is at /BaseFolder, but the application expects that this directory is at /BaseFolder/App.

Adding `os.chdir("app")` to run.py fixes this.  It doesn't explain why the app expects different paths at different locations, though.